# How can I get the old and new value using directive in Angular 2?

Tags: angular

Does anyone know how can I get the old and new value inside the directive? I need to compare if the value was changed to add a css class.

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of list" [addClass]="item.name">{{item.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

add-class.directive.ts

```
import { Directive, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[addClass]'
})

export class AddClassDirective implements OnInit {
  @Input('addClass') addClass: string;

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.addClass);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

method 1:

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
  if (changes['addClass'] && !changes['addClass'].isFirstChange()) {
    const prev: string = changes['addClass'].previousValue;
    const cur: string = changes['addClass'].currentValue;

    // do something with prev and cur
  }
}
```

method 2:

```
private _addClass: string;

@Input() set addClass(value: string) {
  const prev = this._addClass;
  this._addClass = value;
  const cur = value;

  if (typeof prev !== 'undefined') {
    // do something with prev and cur
  }
}

get addClass() {
  return this._addClass;
}
```

Note that both these methods will also be called when the directive is first initialized. In those cases the previous value will be `undefined` (which you can test for in ngOnChanges using the `isFirstChange()` method).

Comment: Thanks @dbandstra. This worked for me. I did not know the SimpleChanges dependency. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Once I create the directive, do you know when I need to import it in my unit tests? I am getting an [error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44463088/testing-directive-in-angular-2-jasmine-i-am-getting-an-error). Thanks.